# SonarQube 5.6 LTS end-of-support date

Tags: sonarqube

Since 6.7 LTS was released on Nov 8th 2017, when is the previous 5.6 LTS end-of-support date?

(We have developed widgets for the old LTS and need to understand when can we stop supporting them in favor for new plugins)

Comment: You should ask SonarSouce.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered in the SonarQube Google Group : https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/JzgetifU9ik/VruCki39DAAJ.
Answer is 5.6.x is no longer maintained starting 6.7 release date.